# Why is CSS Left 75% and Right 25% working differently?

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I have the following CSS

```
.bloodparam > .highvalue { bottom: 12px; right: 25%; }
```

and

```
.bloodparam > .highvalue { bottom: 12px; left: 75%; }
```

ideally the position of the element must be the same regardless of which one I use, but I see different positions. Any ideas why?

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/956y5/1/ - You'll see the right indicator is different for the first and the second line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`left` position values are calculated *starting* at the specified left value given and puts the width to the *right* of the location

`right` position values are calculated *starting* at the specified right value given and puts the width to the *left* of the location

Visually you can see this in your example, the right part of the top 100 matches up with the left part of the bottom one.

This is for good reason. Take for example the comparison of `left:0` and `right:0`. If they were to be equivalent, the `left` version would be positioned at the far left of the screen with the full width showing, but the `right` version would be positioned at the very far right of the screen and not be visible. As it is, though, it positions the element where the full width is shown but it is at the right most value possible

And technically speaking, both of your values are wrong because `left` and `right` take into account the width of the element it is positioning. To be perfectly accurate you would need to also have a negative margin on one side of half the width of the element being positioned. The error can be easily seen by giving the left value `100%`, the marker then moves outside of the range entirely

Comment: How to then place pointers to exactly 0%, 25%, 50%, 75% and 100%?

Comment: @FilipŠ What do you mean "pointers" and "exactly" those values? A demo would be helpful.

Comment: Something like in this question. To have arrows that points to exect position in colored bar.

Comment: @FilipŠ You'd do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/0qktjg7m/7/) where you use a left or right value and compensate for the width using a transform (as I did in the demo) or a negative margin of half the width of the element.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's different, you have an element with an arbitrary width, and the left and right is being calculated from either the left or the ride side of that. 75% calculated from the left edge is different from the 25% calculated from the right edge that is how ever many pixels away from the left.

Comment: This is correct. If you are looking for a way to fix this issue, you would need to know the width of your element, and apply a negative margin of half of the width in the direction you need.

Answer (score 1):

The 25% and the 75% are the distance between the right element border and the right page borden / the left element border and the left page border. Adding some backgrounds to your fiddle may clarify this (I just added `background-color: blue` to the two elements):

http://jsfiddle.net/956y5/3/